# header guard conundrum - already defined in .obj problem

Tags: c++

I have a class (A) which has to include two files, class X and class Y. unfortunately class Y also needs to include class X in it's header file because the constructor takes a pointer to a class X type as an argument.

The potential problem is that there would be a linker error? as class A now has two copies of class X in it, one that it needs to use, and one from class Y. This is the situation where header guards are of no use. My question is - is this purely a structural problem or is there a way around this?

I really would prefer to not include anything in class Y's header file, in case I want to include THAT in anything else, but is it necessary because of the function prototype?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, so long as you haven't defined any non-inline functions in your header files.  Can you post some representative code?

Comment: actually I'm sorry, I think the error was coming from somewhere else. Even so though, this is good to learn. So as long as the header files contain only prototypes, you can include a number of the same one without any problems?

Comment: You can have the class definition, along with member-function definitions, so long as they're inlined into the class body itself, e.g.: `class X { int foo() { return 1; } };`.  This is not fine: `class X { int foo(); }; int X::foo() { return 1; }`.

Comment: just made a minor edit to the question so it's of more use to the community - it's now a theoretical one, but the content's the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the following:

**X.h**

```
#ifndef X_H__
#define X_H__

class X
{
public:
    int foo() { return 1; }
};

#endif
```

**Y.h**

```
#ifndef Y_H__
#define Y_H__

#include "X.h"

class Y
{
public:
    Y(X *pX) { myval = pX->foo(); }
    int myval;
};

#endif
```

**something.cpp**

```
#include "X.h"

...
```

**something_else.cpp**

```
#include "Y.h"

...
```

Then there should be no problem.

However, if `X.h` instead looks like this:

```
#ifndef X_H__
#define X_H__

class X
{
public:
    int foo();
};

int X::foo() { return 1; }

#endif
```

then you will indeed get a linker error when you try to link `something.cpp` and `something_else.cpp`.  `X::foo` will have been defined non-inline into two separate *translation units*.

Comment: And the workaround...? Noone wants to define methods within a class.

Comment: @TomášZato: The workaround?  There are two options; either you define the member function "inline" in the class definition, or you define it in a separate .cpp file.

Comment: This just saved me so much time. But I still don't get why this is the case. In my code I had a file X.h without a class, just two helper methods. Now I put them inside a class, made them static and it works. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @TomášZato : The problem is not on the method's definition being within a class ( "...a class's declaration within a header." would be more accurate ). The problem is on the method's definition being within a header. :) It must be inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a declaration in the Y header.

```
class X;
```

Since you only use a pointer to X the compiler doesn't need to know it's definition.