# NuGet package restore failed when building Windows Calculator

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am trying to build Windows Calculator ([Microsoft/Calculator on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator)) with Visual Studio 2017 Community version.  I followed the instructions but got an error message starting with:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project Calculator: Unable to find version '1.0.2' of package 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator.PGO'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator.PGO.1.0.2' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator.PGO.1.0.2' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
(......build started and failed)
```

I checked nuget.config found in the repo and it mentions https://eeapps.blob.core.windows.net/eeapps/index.json, which did not appear in the error message.  It seems to me that nuget failed to check this location for packages.  How do I restore the missing packages?

Answer (score 0):

> NuGet package restore failed when building Windows Calculator

To resolve this issue, you should add the specify nuget source (`https://eeapps.blob.core.windows.net/eeapps/index.json`) to the Package Source in the Visual Studio:

Tools->Options->NuGet Package Management->Package Source:

[image]

Then you can see those packages:

[image]

Now, you can restore the nuget packages with the options Restore NuGet Packages when you right click on your solution file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The "restore failed" message disappears but I am still getting "this project references nuget packages that are missing on this computer" error.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I realized the problem actually has nothing to do with NuGet.

I cloned the repo with git on WSL (Ubuntu app), and after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54296216/2201385) I retried cloning with Git on Windows and the problem simply disappears.

It seems that git clone on WSL and Visual Studio just don't get along.  [Related GitHub issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3180).