# "Incomplete type is not allowed" with static inline member of own class

Tags: c++, static, inline

```
struct Foo
{
    inline static Foo F1;
};
```

This causes compilation error on various online compilers of C++11, C++17, C++20 due to `‘Foo Foo::F1’ has incomplete type`. In Visual Studio with C++17 it compiles and runs fine, but with the IntelliSense warning `incomplete type is not allowed`. Why? Is there something potentially hazardous about doing this?

Comment: g++ issues an error for that: [https://godbolt.org/z/MK57P1486](https://godbolt.org/z/MK57P1486)

Comment: "_Is there something potentially hazardous about doing this?_": It is ill-formed.

Comment: It's not "hazardous" as much as it would be complex and confusing to allow a variable declaration with a type that hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Isn't this a recursive definition?  Having a `Foo *` would be a different case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the class definition of `Foo`, `Foo` itself is still incomplete (except in complete-class contexts).

`inline` makes the static data member declaration a definition and in a definition of a variable its type must be complete.

However, you can add the `inline` later. You just need to make sure that this external definition is present in every translation unit that includes the class definition (i.e. put it directly under the class in the header):

```
struct Foo
{
    static Foo F1;
};

inline Foo Foo::F1;
```

Comment: This doesn't compile if I refer to `F1` in some other class.

Comment: @H.v.M. Works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/Tdzr5xaqr

Comment: Another file, then. Or "translation unit" I guess? The same definition will be in multiple .obj files, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15421368/1715765

Comment: @H.v.M. As long as you put `inline` on the definition and include that definition in every translation unit, it is ok to have it be emitted in every .obj file. That's the point of `inline`.

Comment: Still doesn't compile though. Here's all that seems like it could be relevant. Do you spot anything wrong?
stdafx.h: `#pragma once #include "TpGlobals.h"`
TpGlobals.h: `#pragma once struct Foo [...]`
Bar.h: `#pragma once`
Bar.cpp: `#include "stdafx.h" #include "Bar.h" Foo f = Foo::F1;`

Comment: @H.v.M. That's a single translation unit. What is it complaining about?

Comment: @H.v.M. Also, I don't know whether MSVC's `"stdafx.h"` mechanism implies any restrictions on what can be put in that header file. It is completely non-standard.

Comment: Well there's also Baz.cpp. I think multiple cpp files which #include the `F1` definition is the problem, and referring to `F1` somewhere just causes the problem to not be ignored.
`1>Bar.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static struct Foo Foo::F1" (?F1@Foo@@2U1@A) already defined in Baz.obj
1>   Creating library C:\Dev\Repos\foo\Build\Debug\Foo.lib and object C:\Dev\Repos\foo\Build\Debug\Foo.exp
1>C:\Dev\Repos\foo\Build\Debug\Foo.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Comment: Same problem if I remove `TpGlobals.h` from `stdafx.h` and #include it directly in two cpp files.

Comment: @H.v.M. The compiler shouldn't complain if there is `inline` on the definition. If it does, that's a compiler bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323151/error-lnk2005-already-defined-in-obj-for-inline-member

Answer (score 2):

According to [class.static.data.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#data-3):

> The declaration of a **non-inline static** data member in its class definition **is not a definition** and **may be of an incomplete type** other than cv void.

At the same time [class.static.data.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#data-4):

> ... The declaration of an **inline static** data member (**which is a definition**) may specify a brace-or-equal-initializer. ...

Also [basic.def.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#5):

> In the **definition** of an object, the type of that object **shall not be an incomplete type** ([basic.types.general]), an abstract class type ([class.abstract]), or a (possibly multidimensional) array thereof.

(emphasis mine)

This implies that declarations of `inline static` data members, unlike just `static`, are definitions and thus mustn't be of an object of incomplete type, so your example is ill-formed and your Visual Studio wrongly accepted it. The latest msvc doesn't ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5sGahMe9x)), though, so that's been already resolved.